# Restrict the user from adding one item multiple time to cart in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have created a website in php. I have provided a cart feature in it. when the user clicks the add to cart button, they should be redirected to the cart page with the item displaying. The library.php which process the code for the cart is below:

```html
<?php

// load database connection script

include("database_connection.php");

/*
 * Tutorial: PHP MySQL Shopping cart
 *
 * Page: Application library
 * */

class ShopingCart
{



    protected $db;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = DB();
    }

    /**
     * get products list
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        $query = "SELECT *  FROM `entertainment`";
        if (!$result = mysqli_query($this->db, $query)) {
            exit(mysqli_error($this->db));
        }
        $data = [];
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $data[] = $row;
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }

    /**
        * get given product details
        *
        * @param [integer] $id
        * @return array
        */
       public function getProductDetails($id)
       {
           $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->db, $id);
           $query = "SELECT *  FROM `entertainment` WHERE `id` = '$id'";
           if (!$result = mysqli_query($this->db, $query)) {
               exit(mysqli_error($this->db));
           }
           $data = [];
           if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
               while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                   $data['id'] = $row['id'];
                   $data['title'] = $row['title'];
                   $data['price'] = $row['vendor_price'];
                   $data['quantity'] = 1;
               }
           }

           return $data;
       }

       /**
        * Add new product into the cart
        *
        * @param [integer] $id
        * @return void
        */
       public function addToCart($id)
       {

         $product = $this->getProductDetails($id);

         $isFound = false;
         $i = 0;

         if (!isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) || count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) < 1)
         {
             $_SESSION['shopping_cart'] = array(0 => $product);
         } else {

             foreach ($_SESSION['shopping_cart'] as $item) {
                 $i++;
                 foreach ($item as $key => $value) {
                     if ($key == "id" && $value == $id) {
                         array_splice($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], $i - 1, 1, array([
                             'id' => $item['id'],
                             'title' => $item['title'],
                             'price' => $item['vendor_price'],
                             'quantity' => $item['quantity'] + 1,
                         ]));
                         $isFound = true;
                     }
                 }

             }
             if ($isFound == false) {
                 array_push($_SESSION['shopping_cart'], $product);
             }
         }

       }

       /**
        * remove existing product from the cart
        *
        * @param [integer] $id
        * @return void
        */
       public function removeProductFromCart($id)
       {
           unset($_SESSION['shopping_cart'][$id - 1]);
       }


}

?>
```

and my cart php file looks like below:

```html
<?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) && count($_SESSION['shopping_cart']) > 0)
                    {
                        $entertainment = $_SESSION['shopping_cart'];

                        echo '
                                <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Title</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
                                    <th scope="col">Price</th>
                                    <th scope="col" width="100">Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>';

                        $item_number = 1;
                        $total = 0;
                        foreach ($entertainment as $product) {
                        echo '
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                    <th scope="row">'. $item_number .'</th>
                                    <td>' . $product['title'] . '</td>
                                    <td>'.$product['quantity'].'</td>
                                    <td>₹ '. $product['price']. '</td>
                                    <td>
                                        <a href="cart.php?id_to_remove=' . $item_number . '" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">X</a>
                                    </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                           ';
                           $total += ((int)$product['price'] * $product['quantity']);
                            $item_number++;
                        }

                        echo '
                                <tr>
                                    <th colspan="4" align="right">
                                        Total:
                                    </th>
                                    <td>
                                        ₹ '. $total .'
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </table>';

                    }
```

Actually I have referred to the internet to make this cart. the cart is working fine. But the problem is I need to restrict the user from adding one item multiple times, user should only add an item only once, that is the quantity of the item should be only 1, when the user tries to add more times one item, they should be alerted.

Can anyone tell me how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can eliminate duplicate value from the array of values by adding :

```
array_unique($yourArray);
```

If your array have those values:

```
$yourArray = ['a','b','c','b'];
$array = array_unique($yourArray);
//$array = ['a','b','c'];
```